# Why Numba does not work when I'm calling a function over and over into another?

Tags: numpy, matrix, numba, eigenvalue, skew

I have a code to calculate skewness over 100 matrices or more. The matrix is actually a directed percolation. I defined 2 functions. the first: `doPercolationStep()` defines how does this *random* matrix should be filled. The second: `manual(hl)` produces this matrix over and over which means calls the `doPercolationStep()` over and over then calculates skewness of these *random matrices*. When I run the code with Numba I get This error:

```
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> setitem(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 1d, C))
 
There are 16 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 16 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
    With argument(s): '(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 1d, C))':
   No match.

During: typing of setitem at <timed exec> (55)

File "<timed exec>", line 55:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

My First function is :

```
%%time
import numpy as np 
import random as rand
from numba import jit , njit , prange
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linalg as la
import statistics as stt

@njit(parallel=True)
def doPercolationStep(vector, PROP, time):
    
    even = time%2
    vector_copy = np.copy(vector)
    WIDTH = len(vector)
    for i in range(even, WIDTH, 2):
        if vector[i] == 1:
            
            pro1 = np.random.rand()
            pro2 = np.random.rand()
            if pro1 < PROP:
                vector_copy[(i+WIDTH-1)%WIDTH] = 1
            if pro2 < PROP:
                vector_copy[(i+1)%WIDTH] = 1
            vector_copy[i] = 0
    return vector_copy
```

And my main function is :

```
li=700 
@njit(parallel=True)
def manual(hl):
    WIDTH = hl
    HEIGHT = hl
    #PROP = 0.644
    L = hl
    p = linspace(0.1,0.9,15)
    nx = len(p)
    N = 100000
    sk=[]
    ku = []
    for ip in range(nx):

        w0=[]

        for i in range(N):
            vector = np.zeros(WIDTH)
            vector[WIDTH//2] = 1
            PROP=p[ip]
            result = []
#result.append(vector)
            for i in range(HEIGHT):
                vector=doPercolationStep(vector, PROP, i)
                result.append(vector)
            #np.savetxt('result.dat', result, fmt='%d')
            ss=np.array(result)
            ss=ss.astype(np.int64)
            ##ss=np.int(result)
            ###ss= result
            ss = np.where(ss==0, -1, ss)
            ww=(ss+(ss.T))/2
            re_size=ww/(np.sqrt(L))
            w, v = la.eigh(re_size)
            w=w.real
            w=max(w)
            w0.append(w)
        w1=np.array(w0)    
        w1_mean=np.mean(w1)
        w1_std=np.std(w1)
        w1_std_3=(w1_std)**3
        w1_num=N
        w1_3=0
        for ai in w1:
            w1_3+=(ai-w1_mean)**3
    
        w1_skew=(w1_3)/((w1_num)*(w1_std_3))
        sk.append(w1_skew)
        #kyu=kurtosis(w0)
        #ku.append(kyu)
        
    return  sk
    
manual(li)
```

And finally, I get this error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> setitem(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 1d, C))
 
There are 16 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 16 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
    With argument(s): '(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 1d, C))':
   No match.

During: typing of setitem at <timed exec> (55)

File "<timed exec>", line 55:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Comment: The error message is typical of having a function using some non-supported operations in Numba. I would suggest to check if the linalg module is actually supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing the relevant part of the error:

```
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:

 >>> setitem(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 1d, C))

There are 16 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 16 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
    With argument(s): '(array(undefined, 1d, C), int64, array(float64, 1d, C))':
   No match.

During: typing of setitem at /home/jotaele/Devel/codetest/tests/test_numba.py (2452)

File "test_numba.py", line 2452:
        def manual(hl):
            <source elided>
                        vector = doPercolationStep(vector, PROP, i)
                        result.append(vector)
                        ^
```

This tells you exactly what's happening.
Python's [`setitem(a,b,c)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html?highlight=setitem#operator.setitem) sets the value of a at index b with the value in c.
In your case, `result` receives the value, but it is defined as `[]`, so Numba doesn't know its type.

You need to initialize it as an array whose size and type you know in advance. Your code is now shorter and runs with Numba:

```
    ...
    PROP = p[ip]
    ss = np.empty((HEIGHT, WIDTH), dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(HEIGHT):
        ss[i] = doPercolationStep(vector, PROP, i)
    ss = np.where(ss == 0, -1, ss)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now. But I don't get it. Doesn't Numba know a list? or it has some problems with the way that I created the list?